# Images not showing on specific sites on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

https://impress.openneo.net/ uses images from http://images.neopets.com - they work fine in the Neopets.com site itself, but show as broken in impress.openneo.net

They also show broken in https://neocodex.us/forum/ but the site is down atm

What I tried so far: removing extensions, clearing cookies and cache, hard refresh

I use beta Chrome, the normal version refuses to install.
It shows fine if I access it via Opera or Firefox. Any help is much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The images from http://images.neopets.com/ are embedded on https://impress.openneo.net/ using HTTP instead of HTTPS. Chrome tries to retrieve the resources via HTTPS, but images.neopets.com uses a wrong SSL certificate, which prevents Chrome from loading the images.

Firefox for example displays a warning sign on the security icon (the lock) to the left of the address bar, but loads the images anyway (using HTTP). The warning sign indicates that parts of the connection are unsafe (the images in this case), because they are retrieved via HTTP.

To prevent this, you can visit https://images.neopets.com/ via HTTPS, which will show a warning about the insecure connection, where you can open the Advanced options and proceed to the site (ignoring the fact, that a wrong certificate is used). Now the other sites should show the images properly.

Comment: Wow, I'd never have figured it by myself. Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: @Matheus I changed the answer based on your comment.